# Dynamically select the table to join in Postgres with case statements

Tags: sql, postgresql

My notifications table has a column called `action_id` and `trigger_type`. I want to INNER JOIN `action_id` with another table (Like users or posts) depending on the `trigger_type`. I wrote the following query but it throws an error.

**Table structure**

**users**

| display_name | username | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Doe | 1 |
| Larry | Doe | 2 |

**posts**

| post_title | post_body | id | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Hello | Hello world | 1 | 2 |

**comments**

| comment_text | post_id | id | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Hello | 1 | 1 | 1 |

**notifications**

| read | trigger_id | id | target_id | action_id | trigger_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| false | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| false | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 |

trigger_type = 0 means its a like 1 means its a comment

```
SELECT notifications.*, users.display_name, users.username, users.profile_pic, posts.title
 
FROM notifications 

INNER JOIN users ON users.id = notifications.trigger_id 
(
  CASE notifications.trigger_type 
    WHEN 0 THEN INNER JOIN users ON users.id = notifications.action_id 
    WHEN 1 THEN INNER JOIN posts ON posts.id = notifications.trigger_id
)
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you want to achieve with that. You're joining `users`, then again `users` in your `case`. This `case` is not possible AFAIK but what you can do is either dynamic sql (created in procedure or by something external like Python) or you may want to have left joins both to `users` and `posts` and then have this whole `case when`  in `select` part.

Comment: And you're missing `END` in `CASE`.

Comment: Please post table structure, some sample data and desired output for better understanding

Comment: It's unclear to me if you want to join users twice or only once. Also what is the expected output for users.display_name if the trigger type is 1? Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as formatted text. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. (please [edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Are you maybe looking for: `FROM notifications n
  LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = n.trigger_id AND n.trigger_type = 0
  LEFT JOIN posts p ON p.id = n.trigger_id AND n.trigger_type = 1
`

Comment: @AkhileshMishra Added table structure. Can you please take a look now?

Comment: @AdamTokarski Thank you very much for your time. How about going for a left join?

Comment: @RavinHewage please see answer from @a_horse_with_no_name - it may work. But still you'd need to say whether you really want to join `users` twice and ideally would be if you had add desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot conditionally join like that.  Instead, use `left join` like this:

```
SELECT n.*,
       -- whatever columns you want from the trigger user go here
       un.display_name, un.username, un.profile_pic, p.title
FROM notifications n JOIN
     users u
     ON u.id = n.trigger_id LEFT JOIN
     users un
     ON un.id = n.action_id AND n.trigger_type = 0 LEFT JOIN
     posts p
     ON p.id = n.action_id AND n.trigger_type = 1;
```